# Graphing Rows in Python

Tags: python, graphing

I have a task that i am just starting and i am very new to python. All help is appreciated.

So i have a large Excel CSV file and i would like to graph some things from it. 
Right now i am just trying to get some names onto the Y-Axis of the graph. 
Here is a photo, and i have highlighted the names that i want graphed, these names continue in this row for another 109 cells. 
[image: Data]

The next step for me will be to have the time column on the X-axis. 
My main problem is that one axis is a row and another is a column. and when i try to write any code, it is very hard because i have to transpose the CSV to graph the Y-Axis but i do not have to Transpose for the X-Axis. Can anyone please help? 
Thank you very much

Update 1:

```
 with open('CSV_GM_NB_1_0_Functional_Initial_5_pt.csv', 'rb') as 
longishfile:
    reader=csv.reader(longishfile)
    rows= list(reader)

print(rows[3])
```

Comment: What code did you try so far?

Comment: Well, i used the CSV reader and i tried pandas, but i really didn't get anything to work, and deleted most of it, then turned to here for help. so all i have left is what i have put in above. However i know that it is not correct at all, and i need to start from scrath but dont know where to start.

Comment: Try a beginners tutorial on python loops, python lists (and list of lists), pandas and matplotlib :)